# Using ng-transclude inside a ng-include template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

When trying to use ng-transclude inside a ng-include template it throws a below error,

`Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. Element: <ng-transclude>`

I do have included the `transclude: true` inside the directive scope,

```
// directive1.html
<div>
    <div ng-include="template.html">
</div>

// template.html
<div>
  <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</div>
```